# Failed to connect to dev.azure.com port 443: Timed out error: Could not fetch origin

Tags: git, azure

I have a huge problem connecting to a repository in Azure DevOps. When changing a branch in the local repository or trying to refresh, the following errors occur

```
PS H:\damian\Azure DevOps\xxx> git remote update origin --my_branch
Fetching origin
fatal: unable to access 'https://dev.azure.com/xxx/': 
Failed to connect to dev.azure.com port 44: Timed out
error: Could not fetch origin
```

After clearing the credential manager, new errors appear when trying to switch to another branch

```
> git checkout -q xxx
error: cannot stat 'Generic_initializaton/Libraries_and_Settings.sas': Function not implemented
error: cannot stat 'Generic_framework_macros/ABT_structure_verification.sas': Function not implemented
```

Generally the whole list of scripts is generated - as if GIT doesn't see it

Please help, I've never seen this before and I'm running out of ideas

Comment: Can you include more details? The first command you are running appears to be a network timeout. What credential manager are you using and how does it relate to the second error? You've used `xxx` to redact things, but they might be important. Show an example to duplicate your issue.

Comment: @damian: You have a problem with VPN/Proxy settings, most probably. I'd suggest checking these settings first